# OpenGL ES use in a headless embedded linux platform

Tags: c, linux, opengl-es, yocto

In our project we want to use the GPU of a Freescale iMX6Q ARM processor to render an image and then write over a gstreamer pipeline to a VNC server.
The sequence is as follows:

- Initialize OpenGL
- For each frame of the video stream:

  1. Render Image with OpenGL ES to a texture using a Framebuffer and a
     Renderbuffer
  2. Read Image pixels using `glReadPixels()`
  3. Copy the Image data to the video frame
  4. Push frame to the video stream

We use Yocto 1.8 as the build-system, and the source code below of the init sequence works on our nitrogen6X-lite prototype board (with `USE_PBUFFER` defined), but not on our headless production board. On the production board we can't initalize a "display": Either with `USE_PBUFFER` defined or not defined, we get a `0x3003 EGL_BAD_ALLOC` Error. We have the `vfb` kernel module loaded with `vfb_enable=1` and the `video=vfb` kernel options. The dev file `/dev/fb0` is created successfully. In yocto, we tried the `fsl-image-multimedia-full`, `image-core` and `image-core-directfb` images both in default mode, and wtih

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = " x11 wayland"
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " directfb"
```

in our `conf/local.conf` file.

**How should can we use the GPU of the iMX processor in an embedded Linux settings to render offscreen, without having a display? What are the appropriate Kernel settings? What are the appropriate user-space functions to use?**

Current user-space implementation of the OpenGL init sequence:

```
EGLDisplay display;
EGLSurface surface;
#ifdef  USE_PBUFFER
  display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
#else
 int fbnum = 0; // fbnum is an integer for /dev/fb0 fbnum = 0
 EGLNativeDisplayType native_display = fbGetDisplayByIndex(fbnum);
 EGLNativeWindowType native_window = fbCreateWindow(native_display, 0, 0, 0, 0);
 display = eglGetDisplay(native_display);
#endif  
if (display == EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
 g_print("Unable to open connection to Window system: 0x%x\n",eglGetError());
 return 0; // <-- Point of failure, both with and without USE_PBUFFER set
}
// ...
if (!eglInitialize(display, &majorVersion, &minorVersion)) {
 g_print("Unable to initialize Display: 0x%x\n",eglGetError());
 return 0;
}
// ...
#ifdef USE_PBUFFER
  surface = eglCreatePbufferSurface(display, config, surfaceAttribList); 
#else
  surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, native_display, surfaceAttribList);
#endif
```

Extract of the current kernel config, based on 3.14.28

```
# CONFIG_VGASTATE is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_OUTPUT_CONTROL is not set
CONFIG_HDMI=y
CONFIG_FB=y
# CONFIG_FIRMWARE_EDID is not set
# CONFIG_FB_DDC is not set
# CONFIG_FB_BOOT_VESA_SUPPORT is not set
CONFIG_FB_CFB_FILLRECT=y
CONFIG_FB_CFB_COPYAREA=y
CONFIG_FB_CFB_IMAGEBLIT=y
# CONFIG_FB_CFB_REV_PIXELS_IN_BYTE is not set
CONFIG_FB_SYS_FILLRECT=m
CONFIG_FB_SYS_COPYAREA=m
CONFIG_FB_SYS_IMAGEBLIT=m
# CONFIG_FB_FOREIGN_ENDIAN is not set
CONFIG_FB_SYS_FOPS=m
# CONFIG_FB_SVGALIB is not set
# CONFIG_FB_MACMODES is not set
# CONFIG_FB_BACKLIGHT is not set
CONFIG_FB_MODE_HELPERS=y
# CONFIG_FB_TILEBLITTING is not set
#
# Frame buffer hardware drivers
#
# CONFIG_FB_IMX is not set
# CONFIG_FB_UVESA is not set
# CONFIG_FB_OPENCORES is not set
# CONFIG_FB_S1D13XXX is not set
# CONFIG_FB_TMIO is not set
# CONFIG_FB_SMSCUFX is not set
# CONFIG_FB_UDL is not set
# CONFIG_FB_GOLDFISH is not set
CONFIG_FB_VIRTUAL=m
# CONFIG_FB_METRONOME is not set
CONFIG_FB_MX3=y
# CONFIG_FB_BROADSHEET is not set
# CONFIG_FB_AUO_K190X is not set
# CONFIG_FB_MXS is not set
# CONFIG_FB_SIMPLE is not set
# CONFIG_EXYNOS_VIDEO is not set
# CONFIG_BACKLIGHT_LCD_SUPPORT is not set
CONFIG_FB_MXC=y
# CONFIG_FB_MXC_SYNC_PANEL is not set
CONFIG_FB_MXC_EDID=y
# CONFIG_FB_MXC_EINK_PANEL is not set
```

**Update 2015-09-24:** 
Well, as a first step to resolve the issues, we added the correct MXC framebuffer drivers to the kernel and the device tree, but we still keep getting EGL_BAD_ALLOC Errors (both when x11 and wayland are added to the image or not). We use the following kernel command line:

```
[..] video=mxcfb0:dev=hdmi,1920x1080M@60,if=RGB24 gpumem=64M fbmem=32M,32M [..]
```

Also, the device files `/dev/fb0` and `/dev/fb1` are created correctly and the output on `/sys/class/graphics/fb0` resp. `fb1` is looking reasonable (i.e. same as on my desktop pc and my nitrogen reference board)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://community.freescale.com/thread/375384 this is a compatibility issue between the 3.14.28 Kernel and the Vivante libs for the imx6 processor. The solution is therefore going back to anothee kernel version.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the problem you're running into is, that you're attempting to open a "native" display, which expects to run on some kind of display device. This is not going to work on a headless system, obviously.

Since you're using EGL, you need some kind of "display" that your particular version of EGL knows how to talk to. However you removed everything that would do the trick (`DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = " x11 wayland"`). Now here's the thing:

You're totally overthinking/overengineering the whole thing; assuming there's proper Wayland support.

If you can use Wayland, instead of doing the "render to FBO with texture/renderbuffer attached then glReadPixels" dance, you could implement a VNC Wayland system compositor, i.e. a Wayland compositor that provides a system "display" that's backed by VNC (or you use the existing implementation of RealVNC http://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/wayland/ ). Since the Wayland protocol itself is GPU agnostic this allows your application to use the GPU while the graphics output will be redirected to the VNC server simply by the VNC server being the compositor.

Comment: Thank you. The reason for the "Render to FBO dance" is, that the output of the OpenGL rendering is mixed with other videostreams before sent out to the VNC. I assume, that would also be possible in your proposed solution.

Comment: @StefanRiesen: Yes, it's called Wayland *compositor* for a reason. A compositor gets the framebuffer contents from the clients and can compose them in whatever fashion it likes to.